# I have a SQL query with a Union. I need only include data in second query if field in first query does not include result from column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with data from two systems. System A is new and includes all modes of transport. System B is a legacy system and data isn't removed when customers move to System A. I work in transportation, and the legacy system on dealt with one type of shipment, while A includes all types. Because some customers are in legacy still I need the data, but customers in the new system are getting duplicates as all legacy data was migrated to the new system.

I have a query with a union that pulls data from System A and B. I need to create a filter that will not include any data from the second query if a field in the first query = x.

ex:

```
select 
a.customer,
a.carrier,
a.mode,
a.shipmentdate

from NewSystem a

Union

select
b.customer,
b.carrier,
'mode type' as Mode,
b.shipmentdate

from OldSystem b
```

In the second query since there was no selection of Mode I have hard coded a Mode type for that column. I need to somehow show that if Mode in A = Mode Type then exclude results from B. I have tried to alias the entire query and use a case statement but it doesn't seem to be removing results.

Comment: could you please provide some your sample data and expected output in tabular format

Comment: You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62703287/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: @taylor15 please look at (EXCEPT and INTERSECT) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Why can't you use DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data this is something of a guess, but I think you're looking for `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT 
   a.customer
  ,a.carrier
  ,a.mode
  ,a.shipmentdate
FROM NewSystem AS a

UNION

SELECT 
   b.customer
  ,b.carrier
  ,'mode type' AS Mode
  ,b.shipmentdate
FROM OldSystem AS b
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1
    FROM NewSystem AS ns
    WHERE ns.customer = b.customer
      AND ns.carrier = b.carrier
      AND ns.shipmentdate = b.shipmentdate
      AND ns.mode = 'mode type'
  );
```

This will only return rows in the second data set that do not have a corresponding row in the first data set.